# Is there any difference using the Change, Input, and Click event for a radio button?

Tags: javascript

It seems a radio button has `change`, `input`, and `click` event. Is there any difference using one other than the other?

(note: the `click` event is actually triggered by the keyboard choosing the radio button in browsers I checked before, but if `click` is to be avoided, is there any difference between `change` and `input` -- does it matter if we use one or the other?).

```js
let radioEl = document.querySelector('#my-lovely-radio-button');

radioEl.addEventListener("change", (ev) => console.log("In Change Handler:", ev.target.value));

radioEl.addEventListener("input", (ev) => console.log("In Input Handler:", ev.target.value));

radioEl.addEventListener("click", (ev) => console.log("In Click Handler:", ev.target.value));
```

```css
label {
  margin-right: 20px
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" id="my-lovely-radio-button" name="choice" value="choice1"> Choice 1</label>

<label><input type="radio" id="my-lovely-radio-button-2" name="choice" value="choice2"> Choice 2</label>
```

Comment: *change* event would be all inclusive of the rest. For example, it possible to change a radio button with the keyboard.

Comment: Keep in mind a radio button can be changed by the keyboard too, as well as via other JS, not just by clicking on it.

Comment: @GetSet the `click` event actually is trigger by the keyboard for radio buttons

Comment: @nonopolarity i didn't know that but makes sense nowadays. Is it cross-browser? A *click* event, to have code in place to detect that and do something else, is infinitely useful.

Comment: @nonopolarity There is one big difference I can think of. That is the order of event handling in a browser, say you chose to use `change` as opposed to `click`, the change event may be higher in the event execution chain, so for instance, I had some events in one of my projects. I was using `click` on an anchor element but had some event function that removed this element when the parent's `blur` event was raised, this caused issues. I had to use `mousedown` on the anchor tag to execute the function associated with the anchor element before the `blur` event of the parent

Comment: @RyanWilson thats where prevent default and the like comes in. And also code to prevent bubbling.

Comment: @GetSet Clicking an element and stopping its `propagation` would not stop the `blur` event attached to the parent, it would stop the `click` event from bubbling. `preventDefault` would only stop the anchors default behavior which is to perform a navigation of the browser to the `href` attribute

Comment: @RyanWilson prevent default maybe. But there are js nomenclature to stop bubbling. Maybe you misunderstood me.

Comment: @GetSet Please read my comment again. `preventDefault` only stops the elements default behavior, in my example, it would be navigation of the browser to the `href` of the anchor. `stopPropogation` would only be good for the current event which was triggered on the element. Since `click` and `blur` are two different events, it would have no affect. (https://medium.com/@jacobwarduk/how-to-correctly-use-preventdefault-stoppropagation-or-return-false-on-events-6c4e3f31aedb)

Comment: Okay @RyanWilson I see your point. So basically you are saying nothing is implied. But you as the architect couldn't you *imply* it?

Comment: @GetSet I'm saying there are cases where the order of event handling matters. So, the OP may want to consider this when choosing the event for their radio button.

Comment: @RyanWilson *change* is the last in any order.

Comment: @GetSet Ok. So like I said, if another event which executed before `change` which affected the OP's radio button event in some way existed, then `change` would be no good or the other event may need modified in a way to prevent the interference.

Comment: @RyanWilson of course other events fire befor *change* but if OP is not handling them your hypothetical is pointless. You gave your own example on an anchor tag which u handled incorrectly. I believe u looked for `onmousedown`.

Comment: @GetSet It's not pointless at all. As neither you nor I know for sure if the OP is or isn't. The point of my comment was to guard against the hypothetical which I mentioned.

Comment: `nor I know for sure` maybe u should re-read.

Answer (score 0):

**Click** event suits the **radio button** because **it is either clicked or not** but Change event is for the input element before submit or click.